# Trigger Custom Dropdown w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, prototype, jquery-events, dropdown

Ultimately, I want to toggle a select dropdown when an image is clicked. I want to utilize the "open/close" function, which is defined in the custom jQuery library, but can't figure out how to access the "open" function.

**Question:** How do I access the "open" or "close" function defined in a custom jQuery library? (More details below - *please note*, I have zero experience using jQuery Prototypes, which is a big part of this problem - I'm not even sure if I can access the object properly.)

**Any help/suggestions or guidance is appreciated**

---

I am using the [Codrops Simple Effects for Dropdowns](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/29/simple-effects-for-drop-down-lists/) article for reference.

Specifically, I am referencing [Demo #4](http://tympanus.net/Development/SimpleDropDownEffects/index4.html) in my example/question.

---

The example uses a custom jQuery library for styling/animating dropdowns:

- This is the [code repo (SimpleDropDownEffects)](https://github.com/rockmandew/SimpleDropDownEffects)
- Here is the [raw code (jquery.dropdown.js)](https://github.com/rockmandew/SimpleDropDownEffects/blob/master/js/jquery.dropdown.js)

---

It's fairly simple:

1. First you lay out your HTML "select" (dropdown) markup

   ```
   <select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
       <option value="-1" selected>Choose an animal</option>
       <option value="1" class="icon-monkey">Monkey</option>
       <option value="2" class="icon-bear">Bear</option>
       <option value="3" class="icon-squirrel">Squirrel</option>
       <option value="4" class="icon-elephant">Elephant</option>
   </select>
   ```
2. (After including all necessary project files) You can call your plugin function

   ```
   $( '#cd-dropdown' ).dropdown();
   ```
3. The function then transforms our "select" markup into the following structure

   ```
   <div class="cd-dropdown">
       <span>Choose an animal</span>
       <input type="hidden" name="cd-dropdown">
       <ul>
           <li data-value="1"><span class="icon-monkey">Monkey</span></li>
           <li data-value="2"><span class="icon-bear">Bear</span></li>
           <li data-value="3"><span class="icon-squirrel">Squirrel</span></li>
           <li data-value="4"><span class="icon-elephant">Elephant</span></li>
       </ul>
   </div>
   ```
4. Then the function responds to the click event as specified on their documentation:

> When clicking on the first span, we will apply the class “cd-active” to its parent, the division with the class “cd-dropdown”. When selecting an option, the respective span will get inserted into the first one.

---

Next, the [jquery.dropdown.js file](https://github.com/rockmandew/SimpleDropDownEffects/blob/master/js/jquery.dropdown.js) contains all of the definitions, which is built using the "prototype" method - which as I mention before, I have zero experience using. I won't include the whole file (since there is a [link](https://github.com/rockmandew/SimpleDropDownEffects/blob/master/js/jquery.dropdown.js)) but I will include the two functions I am trying to access and where *I THINK* it is being initialized.

**The Open Function**

```
open : function() {
        var self = this;
        this.dd.toggleClass( 'cd-active' );
        this.listopts.css( 'height', ( this.optsCount + 1 ) * ( this.size.height + this.options.gutter ) );
        this.opts.each( function( i ) {

            $( this ).css( {
                opacity : 1,
                top : self.options.rotated ? self.size.height + self.options.gutter : ( i + 1 ) * ( self.size.height + self.options.gutter ),
                left : self.options.random ? Math.floor( Math.random() * 11 - 5 ) : 0,
                width : self.size.width,
                marginLeft : 0,
                transform : self.options.random ?
                    'rotate(' + Math.floor( Math.random() * 11 - 5 ) + 'deg)' :
                    self.options.rotated ?
                        self.options.rotated === 'right' ?
                            'rotate(-' + ( i * 5 ) + 'deg)' :
                            'rotate(' + ( i * 5 ) + 'deg)'
                        : 'none',
                transitionDelay : self.options.delay && Modernizr.csstransitions ? self.options.slidingIn ? ( i * self.options.delay ) + 'ms' : ( ( self.optsCount - 1 - i ) * self.options.delay ) + 'ms' : 0
            } );

        } );
        this.opened = true;

    },
```

**The Close Function**

```
close : function() {

        var self = this;
        this.dd.toggleClass( 'cd-active' );
        if( this.options.delay && Modernizr.csstransitions ) {
            this.opts.each( function( i ) {
                $( this ).css( { 'transition-delay' : self.options.slidingIn ? ( ( self.optsCount - 1 - i ) * self.options.delay ) + 'ms' : ( i * self.options.delay ) + 'ms' } );
            } );
        }
        this._positionOpts( true );
        this.opened = false;

    }
```

**Calling it All**

```
$.fn.dropdown = function( options ) {
    var instance = $.data( this, 'dropdown' );
    if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );
        this.each(function() {
            instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );
        });
    }
    else {
        this.each(function() {
            instance ? instance._init() : instance = $.data( this, 'dropdown', new $.DropDown( options, this ) );
        });
    }
    return instance;
};
```

**Setting up the Function - Initial Definition**

```
( function( $, window, undefined ) {

'use strict';

$.DropDown = function( options, element ) {
    this.$el = $( element );
    this._init( options );
};

// the options
$.DropDown.defaults = {
    speed : 300,
    easing : 'ease',
    gutter : 0,
    // initial stack effect
    stack : true,
    // delay between each option animation
    delay : 0,
    // random angle and positions for the options
    random : false,
    // rotated [right||left||false] : the options will be rotated to thr right side or left side.
    // make sure to tune the transform origin in the stylesheet
    rotated : false,
    // effect to slide in the options. value is the margin to start with
    slidingIn : false,
    onOptionSelect : function(opt) { return false; }
};

$.DropDown.prototype = {

    _init : function( options ) {

        // options
        this.options = $.extend( true, {}, $.DropDown.defaults, options );
        this._layout();
        this._initEvents();

    },
```

Hopefully, this makes sense to someone and they can help me out.

---

**Conclusion**

In summary, I want to click on an image on the page, which will trigger the same function/effects that is/are executed when the dropdown itself is clicked.

I'm not sure if I am asking the right question so I will ask both:

1. How can I access the function object defined in the prototype?
2. How can I execute the dropdown open function when clicking on another element? (*Note - This won't function like a normal dropdown, which I know is difficult, if not impossible to force open. I'm thinking I should be able to just execute the same function that is being executed when the dropdown is clicked.)

Thanks for your patience and help with this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after various testing I came up with this:

```
$.extend(
  $.DropDown.prototype, {
    open: function() {
      // YOUR CODE HERE
      alert('YYY');
    }
  }
);
```

you can try it on your browser's console directly on the component's website (DEMO 4) you linked in your question:

http://tympanus.net/Development/SimpleDropDownEffects/index4.html

Prototype method "open" is extended, when you click the dropdown you get the alert.
You can easely extend the "close" method in the same way.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

to trigger the dropdown via javascript, you can simply do this:

```
$('.cd-dropdown span').mousedown();
```

Comment: Thanks, I will implement this and try it out. I have no experience with the Prototype function so I was looking into how to extend the open function, I just didnt know what I was searching for so this is a lot of help. Give me a little bit to implement and try out. I will report back with my results.

Comment: The extend can just be placed in my "site-scripts" file correct? It doesn't require any special placement in the library because it is using the object, right?

Comment: There's a problem in my code: the function in not actually extended, it is rewritten. I'm editing the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I was going to say - the function works great, I just don't see its application. Since the alert is called when the box is opened. This is exactly what I am looking for, except, I want to click an image to trigger opening the dropdown. But I think you understand it, based on your last response.

Comment: Also, if you could please provide an explanation as to how you would call your new "extend" in a "$(element).click(function() { });" case. My coworker is concerned that I don't need to extend the function, rather just call the open function. But I think you're on the right track, I'm just trying to include all information and opinions so I hopefully find the appropriate answer. Thanks again for all of your help.

Comment: that's true. if you just need to trigger the open method, simply emulate a click $('.cd-dropdown span').mousedown();

Comment: Wow... it was that easy all along?! WTF lol Well your code is a create learning tool for the Prototype function. Also, I want to ask, why doesn't ".click();" work - why does only ".mousedown()" work?

Comment: I think the reason is it is bound specifically to the mousedown event. you can check it out inspecting the element with firefox and clicking the "EV" icon next to the element. it will show all events bound to it.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help @GrafiCode Studio - much appreciated.